# Count number of words inside a div - ignoring those inside a specified child div

Tags: jquery

I am looking to count the number of words inside a specified div. The specified div - has a child div included with the class `ignoreMe` - I have a nice bit of code working well to count the words in the parent div INCLUDING the contents of the ignoreMe div... what I cant see to get working is to get the code to ignore the content in the ignoreMe div... any tips on how to achieve this?

```
function countWordsInDiv () {
var txt = $(".parentDIV").text();
wordCount = txt.replace( /[^\w ]/g, "" ).split( /\s+/ ).length;
console.log(wordCount)
}
$(window).load(function() { countWordsInDiv(); });
```

Comment: Take a look, for example, at my library [reading-time](https://github.com/tomik23/reading-time). There you have the option of setting an item that is not included in the word count. The problem is more with counting words due to the fact that you have different hiragara, korean, katakana and many other encodings ;) It is possible that you will get from the code what you need to count words correctly.

Comment: You could get the amount of words of the ```ignoreMe``` child and subtract it from the total?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could subtract the amount of words from the element you need to ignore.

```js
function countWordsInDiv () {
  console.log(returnWords($(".parentDIV").text()) - returnWords($(".ignoreMe").text()))
}

function returnWords(str) {
  return str.replace( /[^\w ]/g, "" ).split( /\s+/ ).length;
}

countWordsInDiv();

$('#total').text(returnWords($(".parentDIV").text()));
$('#total_to_ignore').text(returnWords($(".ignoreMe").text()));
$('#total_without_ignore').text(returnWords($(".parentDIV").text()) - returnWords($(".ignoreMe").text()));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Total: <span id="total"></span></div>
<div>Total Ignore: <span id="total_to_ignore"></span></div>
<div>Total Without Ignore: <span id="total_without_ignore"></span></div>
<br><br>

<div class="parentDIV">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis molestiae quasi nobis modi minima cupiditate vel totam, rem in, cumque, beatae quod doloribus, minus tenetur libero. Ex possimus, accusamus doloremque.
  <div class="ignoreMe">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta totam veritatis eum, illo impedit? Quo consequuntur deserunt unde quam cumque quae quibusdam debitis pariatur, natus aperiam maiores eaque, quod mollitia?</div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates ea odio esse architecto exercitationem doloribus eos nulla tempore adipisci. Accusamus reiciendis beatae excepturi placeat laborum mollitia eos dolores quod. Laboriosam!
</div>
```

Comment: What a good idea.. no why didn't I think of doing that... i was getting obsessed with trying to use a `:not` selector - this way is much easier - thanks!